# return to the application using phonegap

Tags: cordova

I am not able to return to my application after loading a webpage.Is there any way to return to the application after loading web page in iphone when we use phonegap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is the use case for the PhoneGap ChildBrowser plugin in. See [here](https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ChildBrowser)

Comment: Yes, the ChildBrowser plugin is what you are looking for.